# Java Generics : no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<CAP#1>)

Tags: java, generics

So the questions needs me to design a method d to take in a list and a class and return it's contents back.

```
Write a class D that passes the following test.
jshell> class E { public String toString() { return "E"; }}
jshell> class F extends E { public String toString() { return "F"; }}
jshell> List<E> p = D.add(new ArrayList<E>(), new E())
jshell> List<F> q = D.add(new LinkedList<F>(), new F())
jshell> List<E> r = D.add(D.add(new LinkedList<E>(), new E()), new F())
jshell> List<F> s = D.add(D.add(new ArrayList<F>(), new F()), new F())
jshell> /var
| List<E> p = [E]
| List<F> q = [F]
| List<E> r = [E, F]
| List<F> s = [F, F]
jshell> List<E> x = D.join(p, q) // join q to the end of p
jshell> List<E> y = D.join(p, p)
jshell> List<F> z = D.join(q, q)
jshell> /var
| List<E> p = [E]
| List<F> q = [F]
| List<E> r = [E, F]
| List<F> s = [F, F]
| List<E> x = [E, F]
| List<E> y = [E]
| List<F> z = [F]
```

My current code looks like this

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class D {

    public static <T> List <T> add(List<? super T> s,T t) {   
        s.add(t);
        return new ArrayList<T>(s);
    }
}
```

I keep gettinng this error : no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List)

I'm supposed to input the toString value of this into the ArrayList however
`s.add(t.toString());`
also gives an error

Comment: You have to put `T` inside the `<>`. So instead of `ArrayList<>`, put `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: I did that and got this error :no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<CAP#1>)

Comment: @Schred that won't work, there's no way for you to take a `List<? super T>` and convert it to a `List<T>`

Answer (score 3):

A `List<? super T>` isn't a supertype of a `List<T>`. Even this `return new ArrayList<T>(s);` won't work, since `s` isn't the same type as that new `ArrayList` being created. You also can't take a bunch of objects that are instances of a *supertype* of `T` and return a collection that's `T`. Imagine if `s` were `List<Object>` and `t` were a `String`. Your method would be required to return a `List<String>`, which is impossible unless you somehow know that all the objects in `s` are secretly strings.

Also, why are you adding `t` to `s` and then returning a new ArrayList that's just `s`? You're modifying `s` by doing that.

What you should probably do is

```
public static <T> List <T> add(List<T> s, T t) {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>(s);
    res.add(t);
    return res;
}
```

You could also do this if `t`'s type could be less specific than the elements in `s`.

```
public static <T> List <T> add(List<? extends T> s, T t) {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>(s);
    res.add(t);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh what you said makes so much sense. Thank you!  If you don't mind me asking why is that we are not required to add somethig like ```s.add(t.toString()); ```. Does the java compiler directly refer to the toString method?

Comment: @Lm No, `toString` isn't called automatically. Only when you're concatenating strings is it called (`String.valueOf` actually). That doesn't have anything to do with this though, I just took String as an example. Replace that with Integer if you wish